# multiple subroutine that need multiple sql rollbacks

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, transactions, rollback

What’s your method when you have a scenario like:

I have 8 procedures in C# that calls stored procedure to insert data to different tables. In each procedure I have a transaction rollback , aka ( tran.Rollback(); ) in case of failure and currently commit on successes.

However I need to roll back all the inserts even when some had success (and maybe in the future update) when any one of the procedures was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a TransactionScope, eg:

```
void RootMethod()
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel= IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted})
    {
        /* Perform transactional work here */
        SomeMethod();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted })
  {
        /* Perform transactional work here */
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

[Managing transaction flow using TransactionScopeOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope#ManageTxFlow).

Otherwise your transactions might be nestable.  SQL Server, for instance, supports nested transactions.  A `COMMIT` in a nested transaction isn't a final commit, but a `ROLLBACK` always rolls back all work.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I'll do some reading about TransactionScope.